# How would you describe what the affine parameter is in layman's terms?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

I've been trying to learn it from other sites, but I'm not well-versed enough in mathematics to understand.

Comment: I would be skeptical that an explanation for a layman would need to rely on the use of the affine parameter, and could not be reworded in a way that did not make any use of that concept. There's not really a way to explain the concept without using math, but it's also a pretty technical concept so it's unlikely you need it.

Comment: The downvote seems unfair. Yes, the question is a duplicate but it wasn't an especially obvious duplicate. The meaning of an affine parameter puzzled me in my early days.